# Write a function which verifies if the number it takes as parameter is an Armstrong number or not

Tags: python, function

> Write a function which verifies if the number it takes as parameter is an Armstrong number or not. Armstrong number is the number that,
> it should be equal to the powers of its digits (the power here is the number of digits)

I did with an `if` statement. I need help to make this with a function.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

a = n /1000
b = n/100%10
c = n/10%10
d = n%10

if (a**4)+(b**4)+(c**4)+(d**4) == n:
    print("Its an Armstrong number!")
else
    print("Its Not an Armstrong")
```

Comment: What problem (exactly) do you have to refactor your code as function? If you are not familiar with functions - take a tutorial.

Comment: Also, note that your code will work only for 4-digit numbers

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to work with `str(num)` when dealing with digits of `num`. You can first construct a list of digits by using this `str` trick. Then you can apply `sum` and comprehension to the list.

```py
def is_armstrong(num):
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)] # list of digits
    return sum(d ** len(digits) for d in digits) == num

print(*(x for x in range(10000) if is_armstrong(x))) # armstrong numbers < 10000
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 153 370 371 407 1634 8208 9474
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def is_amstrong_number(n : int):
    return n == sum([int(x)**3 for x in str(n)])
```

You can try this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).